# jquery: matching item clicked on with mapped items

Tags: jquery, dictionary

Here's what I am trying to do:

I have a bunch of href's like so:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='popup'>Word</a>....more stuff....<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='popup'>Another Word</a>...
```

So in my code I have:

```
$('.popup').live('click', function() {

    var selectedPopUp = $(this);

    //get all the popups 
var popupList = $('.popup');

   $.map(popuplist, function(thisPopUp, i) {

       if (selectedPopUp == thisPopUp) { 
          //do something
       }


   });

});
```

I thought I would be able to match up the objects this way but when I log them this is what I get:

selectedPopup : [a.popupObj #]

thisPopUp : `<a class="popupObj" href="#">`

I'm doing this because I need the index # of the selectedPopup because there's an object that holds all these properties for displaying the popups. Obviously I am proceeding in the wrong way here, can someone set me straight?

Thanks

Comment: @Chris: Popuplist = [a.popupObj #, a.popupObj #], which is why i thought I could map through it and get a match, but when I log a mapped item (thisPopUp) I am getting : <a class="popupObj" href="#">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to match up one HTML element with a related set of data, or at least an id. That's a great time to use the `rel` property:

So your word links would look like this:

```
<a rel="1" href="#" class="popup">Word</a>
```

(by the way, don't use `href='javascript:void(0);'` -- just use `preventDefault` on the event object, or return false)

Now, your handler looks like this:

```
$('.popup').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var selectedPopUp = $(this).attr('rel');

    // code follows
});
```

Further, you could make use of the `data` attributes:

```
<a href="#" data-title="My popup title" data-content="Blah blah blah!" class="popup">Word</a>
```

Then your handler looks like this:

```
$('.popup').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var title = $(this).data('title');
    var content = $(this).data('content');

    alert(title+"\n"+content);
});
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/x4YmG/

Also note, you should start using the `on` method to bind events, rather than `live`. Starting with jQuery 1.7, the`live` method is deprecated.

**Related Documentation**

- jQuery `data` - http://api.jquery.com/data/
- jQuery `live` (deprecated) - http://api.jquery.com/live/
- jQuery `on` (new way to bind events) - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Chris: look the question over again, I made a typo - the class is .popup, and thisPopUp is an element with that class. I type too slow and you read too fast. : D

Comment: But the rel prop might be what I need.

Comment: @PruitIgoe Also note, as of jQuery 1.7, you should use `on` to bind events, rather than `live`. I forget still too... updated answer :)

Comment: @Chris can he avoid adding the rel using jquery .index()? (In case there is no other anchor at the same level which might interfere of course )

Comment: No, I don't think basing it on index is the best idea -- the data attributes are the best route. The index (the "order" that the element is in DOM) is not immutable; it is subject to modification by other scripts, or even a browser addon. Either could cause havoc by adding or changing elements, thus disrupting the index and causing your data to be out-of-synch with the DOM. You're best off being as explicit as possible, either with a rel id # that points to a key in some json data, or by actually putting the data into the HTML markup. No surprises that way, and there's no reason to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things here..

`map` is generally used to apply a function to all elements in a collection

for instance,

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
$.map(a, function(e, i) {
  return e + 1;
});
# => [2,3,4,5]
```

What you are looking for instead is `each` which allows you to iterate over a collection of elements.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
$.each(a, function(e, i) {
  if(e % 2 == 0) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
# => 2
# => 4
```

The reason you are getting an error though is because `selectedPopUp = $(this)`.

That means that you are comparing a DOM element (`thisPopUp`) with a jQuery selector (`$(this)`).

Here is a JSFiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/28D3h/2/

Finally, out of curiosity - what exactly do you need to be able to do that actually requires to be able to select the element out of the list?

Comment: I'm working inside a huge custom built framework for some iPad optimization. Each screen(template) has a page_content object, which then itself has objects like buttons{}, textblocks{}, popups{}, etc. popup[0] would contain properties for that popup, so when the user clicks on the popup link I need to determine which indexed popup it is so I can match it to the proper popup properties...the damn thing is nice and convoluted at the same time and not well documented and I am normally an obj-c guy trying to work my way through jquery... : D

Answer (score 0):

If the component has the right logic you can try to get the index of the anchor using the jquery [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function and then compare it with the `i` index of the `.map()` function.

```
$('body').on('click','.popup', function() {

   var selectedPopUp = $(this);

   //get all the popups 
   var popupList = $('.popup');
   $.map(popupList, function(thisPopUp, i) {
      console.log(thisPopUp + ' = ' + selectedPopUp.index() + ' y i = ' + i);

      if (selectedPopUp.index() == i) { 
         alert('you selected me!')
      }
   });
});​
```

Here is a working [example.](http://jsfiddle.net/S2Psk/16/)